# Make Force Close Listener in Android Apps

Tags: android, listener, forceclose

How can i make a listener for any force close error in my app?

I need it for my app to listen any error in it and send error stacktrace by email to me

how can i do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use existing code for this, such as [ACRA](http://acra.ch/). Various analytics services offer similar solutions.

Under the covers, it uses `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`, also used in conventional Java apps.

Comment: it use internet. i dont have personal server. how can send by email?

Comment: @OmidOmidi: "i dont have personal server" -- there are plenty of free services out there, both for servers in general (e.g., Amazon S3 free tier) and for analytics specifically (e.g., BugSense).